# Trying to interact with a component on object hit by raycast, getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my character when it interacts with a box. I have a GameObject Player with a script attached to it to interact with boxes in the game, the script is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerBox : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool active = true;
    public KeyCode key = KeyCode.E;

    float distance = 2F;
    RaycastHit obj;
    BoxManager box;

    void Start () {
        box = GetComponent<BoxManager>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (active && Input.GetKeyDown (key) && Physics.Raycast (this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, out obj, distance)) {
            if (obj.collider.gameObject.tag == "Box") {
                box.Open();
                Debug.Log("aperto " + box);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In the scene there is a GameObject Box with a script to manage the behaviour:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BoxManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Open() {
        Debug.Log ("Dentro");
    }
}
```

The last script should print the log but when I interact with it I get

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   PlayerBox.Update () (at Assets/ETSMB/Script/Use/PlayerBox.cs:23)

How can I correctly set `box` to an instance of an object?

Comment: Are you sure that line number is correct that line number indicates the closing brace from the if. What is null is really what you need to find out ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're looking in the wrong place for the `BoxManager` component when you assign a value to `box` in your `Start()` method:

```
void Start () {
    box = GetComponent<BoxManager>();
}
```

`GetComponent<BoxManager>()` will search for the component `BoxManager` on the *current script's* GameObject (the GameObject of `PlayerBox`, in this case). However, based on your wording it sounds like `BoxManager` and `PlayerBox` are on two different GameObjects, so you can't find the component this way. Trying to do so will just give `box` a value of `null`, which is the reason behind the NullReferenceException when you call `box.Open()`.

What you need to do instead is retrieve `BoxManager` from the object you get back from `Physics.Raycast()` - so remove what's in your `Start()` method, and rewrite the contents of your `Update()` method to:

```
void Update () {
    if (active && Input.GetKeyDown (key) && Physics.Raycast (this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, out obj, distance)) {
        if (obj.collider.gameObject.tag == "Box") {
            // Get the BoxManager from the object that has been hit
            box = obj.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxManager>();
            box.Open();
            Debug.Log("aperto " + box);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @DannyIelpo Great, glad I could help out! Don't forget that once you get an answer that satisfactorily addresses your question, you should accept it (click the checkmark next to it) to indicate to everyone that your problem is solved. (This also gives you some internet points, if that's your thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is:

```
void Start () {
    box = GetComponent<BoxManager>();
}
```

is looking for a BoxManager component on PlayerBox, not your BoxManager game object in the scene. So, if there's not a BoxManager script on the PlayerBox game object, box will be null. Hence, your error message.

There are a number of ways to find objects in the scene (see: [FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)) but the simplest for your example would be to make BoxManager box public:

```
public BoxManager box;

void Start () {
    //box = GetComponent<BoxManager>();
}
```

Then, in the unity editor, drag and drop the BoxManager object from the scene hierarchy onto the box variable of the PlayerBox object's inspector.

Now everything is wired up and you shouldn't get a null pointer exception anymore.

Comment: This works well if there's only a single `BoxManager` in the game, but may not be best suited for the situation where there are multiple boxes (which the OP suggests by saying the player needs to "interact with boxes in the game", plural).